# How use template in kendo grid with html.actionlink()?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I am use template in kendo grid but see error

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'
>
> Template:<a href="/Home/ClientProfile_GeneralData?Length=11&q

```
columns: [
       { field: "Id", title: "id" },
       {
            field: "Name", title: "Product Name",
            Template:@Html.ActionLink("#= Name #",   "ClientProfile_GeneralData", "CrmCProfile",

            null
            ).ToHtmlString();

           {
              title: "Action",
              template: "<a href='http://www.sample.com/'>Edit</a>"
           },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem so instead of Html.ActionLink I have used `<a>` tag with Url.ActionLink helper.

Here is my example code:

```
columns: [{
    field: "ContactName",
    title: "Contact Name",
    template: "<a href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home")/#=CustomerID#'>#= CompanyName #</a>"
}]
```